# Array deserialization only returning 1 element

Tags: c#, .net, xml

As the title says when i deserialize the following file i only get the first (and always the first) element:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServerConnections xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Entries>
    <ServerConnectionEntry>
      <Name>Local</Name>
      <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
      <Port>15556</Port>
      <Username>TestUser</Username>
      <AuthHash>
        <base64Binary>u7a0NN4uOvCrb5t5UWVVEl14Ygo=</base64Binary>
      </AuthHash>
    </ServerConnectionEntry>
    <ServerConnectionEntry>
      <Name>Local2</Name>
      <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
      <Port>15556</Port>
      <Username>TestUser</Username>
      <AuthHash>
        <base64Binary>u7a0NN4uOvCrb5t5UWVVEl14Ygo=</base64Binary>
      </AuthHash>
    </ServerConnectionEntry>
  </Entries>
</ServerConnections>
```

My code to deserialize:

```
var list = (ServerConnections)mSerializer.Deserialize(inputStream)).Entries;
```

and list.Count then is 1. ServerConnections looks like that:

```
public class ServerConnections
{
    public ServerConnectionEntry[] Entries { get; set; }
}
```

There is no exception happening.

**Edit:**
The problem occurs when I include my class that does custom xml serialization (implements IXmlSerializable). What it does is the following:

```
void BigNumber::ReadXml(System::Xml::XmlReader^ reader) {
    reader->ReadStartElement();
    XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer(cli::array<Byte>::typeid);
    cli::array<Byte>^ data = (cli::array<Byte>^)serializer->Deserialize(reader);
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptr(&data[0]);
    BN_bin2bn(ptr, data->Length, mNumber);
}

void BigNumber::WriteXml(System::Xml::XmlWriter^ writer) {
    XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer(cli::array<Byte>::typeid);
    serializer->Serialize(writer, ToByteArray());
}
```

While data contains the correct data after ReadXml the deserializer that works the whole list stops and does not read any additional elements.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see any issue. I've even reproduced your scenario *(complete test enclosed below)* of your code, and it is doing its job correctly.

Try to search elsewhere (e.g. assure that the passed `xml` is the one you are expecting). But serialization is working correctly with your C# class mapping

EDIT: AuthHash class no does the conversion for you from `byte[]` to `base64` and back

```
public class ServerConnections
{
    public ServerConnectionEntry[] Entries { get; set; }
}
public class ServerConnectionEntry
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public AuthHash AuthHash { get; set; }
}
public class AuthHash
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
    public string base64Binary
    {
        get { return Convert.ToBase64String(Hash); }
        set { Hash = Convert.FromBase64String(value); }
    }
}
[TestClass]
public class DeserializationTest
{
    public const string MyXml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<ServerConnections 
   xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" 
   xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">
  <Entries>
    <ServerConnectionEntry>
      <Name>Local</Name>
      <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
      <Port>15556</Port>
      <Username>TestUser</Username>
      <AuthHash>
        <base64Binary>u7a0NN4uOvCrb5t5UWVVEl14Ygo=</base64Binary>
      </AuthHash>
    </ServerConnectionEntry>
    <ServerConnectionEntry>
      <Name>Local2</Name>
      <Host>127.0.0.1</Host>
      <Port>15556</Port>
      <Username>TestUser</Username>
      <AuthHash>
        <base64Binary>u7a0NN4uOvCrb5t5UWVVEl14Ygo=</base64Binary>
      </AuthHash>
    </ServerConnectionEntry>
  </Entries>
</ServerConnections>
";
    [TestMethod]
    public void Deserialization_Has_Two_Elements()
    {
        TextReader reader = new StringReader(MyXml);
        var mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerConnections));

        var list = ((ServerConnections)mySerializer.Deserialize(reader)).Entries;

        Assert.IsTrue(list.Count() == 2);

        Assert.IsTrue(list.First().Name == "Local");
        Assert.IsTrue(list.Last().Name == "Local2");

        Assert.IsTrue(list.First().AuthHash.Hash.Length > 0);
        Assert.IsTrue(list.Last().AuthHash.Hash.Length > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, its not about the deserialization per se but underneath im using an unmanaged class (the AuthHash) and that seems to cause a problem. If i remove the AuthHash from the xml it reads all elements.

Comment: I've showed up how you can do the conversion from base64 to byte[] and back... that should solve all your issues

Comment: Thanks for that, but in my case the AuthHash is an C++/CLI class that wraps an unmanaged object. Thus it needs special "treatment" when serialized/deserialized.

Answer (score 1):

Same here, this seems to work fine for me using code similar to yours.

```
 public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ServerConnections));
        var reader = new StreamReader(@"../../Test.xml");
        var entries = (ServerConnections)deserializer.Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Close();
    }

    public class ServerConnections
    {
        public ServerConnectionEntry[] Entries { get; set; }
    }

    public class ServerConnectionEntry
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Host { get; set; }
        public string Port { get; set; }
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public BinaryCode AuthHash { get; set; }
    }

    public class BinaryCode
    {
        [XmlElement("base64Binary")]
        public string Code { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually found the problem to be my deserialization of the BigNumber AuthHash. It obviously skips to the next element and thus it only reads one of them. The xml-serializer seems to work ok however.

Comment: Deserialization of the AuthHash element works fine with the above if you give it a try (changes the string in each of the two AuthHash elements to make it easier). I suppose you could try using a managed class for the reading & then map to the unmanaged class, as I don't know the ramifications of using the unmanaged class in this example. This does make the mapping to the defined type a bit dirty though

Answer (score 0):

Well fizzlesticks, the problem was that i forgot one tiny little line in the deserialization. It should be like that:

```
void BigNumber::ReadXml(System::Xml::XmlReader^ reader) {
    reader->ReadStartElement();
    XmlSerializer^ serializer = gcnew XmlSerializer(cli::array<Byte>::typeid);
    cli::array<Byte>^ data = (cli::array<Byte>^)serializer->Deserialize(reader);
    pin_ptr<unsigned char> ptr(&data[0]);
    BN_bin2bn(ptr, data->Length, mNumber);
    reader->ReadEndElement();
}
```

The ReadEndElement makes sure it advances to the next node. As i didn't do that the deserializer above had a problem but instead of throwing an exception it just stops parsing and returns what it got so far...